# free memory of struct that has an array of other struct inside - C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, struct, free

I trying to use a dynamic array, when i finish using it, i try to free the memory used and i get this error.

```
free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00652098
```

This are the declarations of the struct variables:

```
struct player {
int played_time;
int min_time;
int max_time;
int errors;
int color;
};

struct Players {
struct player *array;
size_t player_number;
size_t size;
};
typedef struct Players Player_list;
```

This are the method used to manage the dynamic array:

```
void initArray(Player_list *list, size_t initialSize) {
  list->array = (struct player *) malloc(initialSize * sizeof(struct player));
  list->player_number = 0;
  list->size = initialSize;
}

void insertArray(Player_list *list, struct player element) {
  if (list->player_number == list->size) {
    list->size *= 2;
    list->array = (struct player *) realloc(list->array,
            list->size * sizeof(struct player));
  }
  list->array[list->player_number++] = element;
}

void freeArray(Player_list *list) {
  free(list->array);
  list->array = NULL;
  list->player_number = list->size = 0;
 }

int disqualified(Player_list *list, int errors) {
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < list->player_number; i++) {
    if (list->array[i].errors >= errors) {
        return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

And here is how i use it in the main:

```
/**
 * When button is pressed 1 add an error to a random player
 */
void button_s_isr(void) {
    int index = rand() % (players.player_number);
    point_players->array[index].errors = point_players->array[index].errors      + 1;

}

      ... 

int main(void) {

      ...
// set up of GPIO
// get with scanf NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS and MAX_ERRORS values

int i;
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS; i++) {
    struct player player;
    player.color = PLAYER_COLORS[i];
    player.errors = 0;
    player.max_time = 0;
    player.min_time = 0;
    player.played_time = 0;
    insertArray(&players, player);
}

while (disqualified(&players, MAX_ERRORS) != 1) {
// wait
}
printf("\n  Se ha acabdo el juego: ");
freeArray(point_players);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I must say i am quite new to C, sorry if it is difficult to understand.
What i want to do is a dynamic list of struct (players), where each player has own parameters (played_time, min_time , max_time, errors, color). And inside the main i want to have a game where i can control this parameters from each player.
Any help to improve the code is appreciated.

Comment: The code as shown does not reveal any reason why the `free()`ing fails, so the bug must be in the code you do *not* show, although `sizeof_array()` does not really make sense to me.  BTW, the naming used is quiet confusing.

Comment: Ah yes, there is not need to cast the result of `malloc()` & Friends in C, nor is it recommended in any way.

Comment: Perhaps the calls to `malloc()` and/or `realloc()` fail. You should ***really*** add error checking there.

Comment: The additional code is a.) still incomplete and b.) inconsistent. Sry.

Comment: You should not assign the result of `realloc` to the original pointer until you know the operation succeeded; always assign to a temporary pointer first (similarly, you shouldn't update `a->size` until after you know the `realloc` call succeeded).  And why are you adding the size of `struct Player` to the size of `a->array` in `sizeof_array`?  That doesn't make any sense.  Finally, make sure that `array` is not being modified anywhere *except* for the `realloc` call; wonder if you aren't stepping on that pointer somehow.

Comment: variable `num_jugadores` not defined in the posted code.  The `PLAYER_COLORS[]` array not defined in the posted code

Comment: variable names need to indicate content or usage (or better, both).  The array name `a` is meaningless, even in the current context.

Comment: when calling `realloc()`, always place the returned value into a `temp` pointer, then check that `temp` pointer != NULL to assure the operation was successful, and if != NULL, then assign to the target pointer.  Otherwise, when the call to `realloc()` fails, 1) the original pointer will not be recoverable, so a memory leak results  2) any following dereference to that NULL pointer will result in a seg fault event.

Comment: I removed the `sizeof_array()` and added the size in `realloc()` in another way, but i get the same error.

Comment: The code initialises and uses `players`, but it `free()`s `point_players`. Also for neither the one or the other you show us the definition. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the posted code:

1. does not compile
2. is missing definitions for PLAYER_COLORS[i], which is a bad idea to use as the number of players could exceed the available colours in the array.
3. incorrectly calculates the size needed for the `realloc()`
4. fails to check the returned values from functions like `malloc()` and `realloc()`
5. contains a confusing (even for the OP) naming of variables and struct instances
6. is missing the definition for `num_jugadores`
7. incorrectly tries to assign a struct rather than copying the struct
8. fails to declare an instance of `struct Players`

and now, corrected code that compiles cleanly:

caveat: not fully tested

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>  // memcpy()

struct player
{
    int played_time;
    int min_time;
    int max_time;
    int errors;
    int color;
};

struct Players
{
    struct player *array;
    size_t player_number;
    size_t numPlayers;
};


//This are the method used to manage the dynamic array:

void freeArray(struct Players *pArray)
{
    free(pArray->array);
    pArray->array = NULL;
    pArray->player_number = pArray->numPlayers = 0;
}


void initArray( struct Players *pArray )
{
    if( NULL == (pArray->array = malloc(sizeof(struct player)) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        freeArray( pArray );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    pArray->player_number = 0;
    pArray->numPlayers = 1;
}


size_t sizeof_array(size_t size)
{
    return  size * sizeof(struct player);
}


void insertArray(struct Players *pArray, struct player *element)
{
    if (pArray->player_number == pArray->numPlayers)
    { // then currently allocated memory for array of players is full

        struct player *temp = NULL;
        if( NULL == (temp = realloc(pArray->array, sizeof_array(pArray->numPlayers)*2) ) )
        { // then, realloc failed
            freeArray( pArray );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, realloc successful

        pArray->numPlayers *= 2;
        pArray->array = temp;
    }

    memcpy( &(pArray->array[pArray->player_number]), element, sizeof( struct player ) );
    pArray->player_number++;
}

//and here is how i use it in the main method:

#define num_jugadores (20)

int main( void )
{
    int i;
    struct Players playerList;

    initArray(&playerList);

    for (i = 0; i < num_jugadores; i++)
    {
        struct player myPlayer;
        //player.color = PLAYER_COLORS[i];
        myPlayer.errors = 0;
        myPlayer.max_time = 0;
        myPlayer.min_time = 0;
        myPlayer.played_time = 0;
        insertArray(&playerList, &myPlayer);
    }


    //...

    freeArray(&playerList);
} // end function: main
```

Answer (score 0):

An error like this usually occurs because you are writing past the end of declared memory.  While we could probably find the bug by carefully pouring over every line of code, valgrind would find it much faster for you.

Try compiling your code in debug mode, without optimizations, (gcc -g -O0 if you are using gcc) and run your program under valgrind (e.g., valgrind myprog -my-prog-options).  It should flag the error right away.

All this assumes you are running a variant of linux.  If you are using visual studio, there will probably be a similar memory checker, but I don't know what it is or how to run it.
Good Luck!

Comment: i am running it in a raspberry with Raspbian on it